# header hidden on mobile device until pulled down with finger

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm building a mobile website (non-native) to run on an iPhone 4. I need to have some "header" content, about 80 pixels high and 100% wide that is always hidden unless the user swipes/pulls downward on any of the displayed content.

This article does almost exactly what I want:

http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/pull-down-for-navigation-a-responsive-solution/

The problem with that is that it's more complex than what I need and does some add'l things I don't need. I tried wiring it into my existing webapp, but it jacked up all the styles and didn't quite work right. They're using lots of styles I don't want. Before I spend hours more changing their styles and trying to figure out which styles are essential for the pulldown effect, and which are extraneous, I'd like to see if anyone has a simpler way to achieve this.

Objective: Finger-slide downward anywhere on my mobile web page and my hidden header slides down into view. When released, header slides back upward and is invisible again. I need nothing fancier than that.

Related question: what "event" on a mobile browser is triggered when a finger pulls the web page downward? Is that "onscroll" or similar? Or something unique to mobile?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution...but would I have to supply an anchor in the url querystring for that to work? I'd love to not clutter the url with that...is there some other way to do the anchor?

Comment: Yes. I have moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'd like this to occur on any displayed content, you may be able to use an anchor to start the page below the header; thus, pulling down on the page (scrolling up past the "top" of the page) will reveal your header. You can use an onload() javascript event to cause the page to automatically jump to your anchor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
    var urllocation = location.href;
    if(urllocation.indexOf("#anchor") > -1){
        window.location.hash="anchor"; 
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

Comment: I like the approach in theory, but it's not doing what I wanted. All it does is hide the address bar on my iphone, not scroll the top header up out of view. I have placed the anchor tag in various places but always get the same results. Also, there's a bug in your code. It should be if(urllocation.indexOf("#anchor") == -1){

Comment: Correction, it's not hiding the address bar, that's just normal iphone behavior a few seconds after the page loads. The anchor thing really isn't working at all, not sure why.